# Android Emulator: Process finished with exit code -529697949

Tags: java, android, android-studio, emulation

I am on Windows 10 with AMD Ryzen 2400G, Android Studio 3.2.1, JDK 1.8, Android Emulator 28.0.22, Android SDK Platform 28.0.1, Android SDK Tools 26.1.1.

When I start Android Emulator (Android 9 x86_64) it starts successfully but after about 1 minute it closes with this error: **Emulator: Process finished with exit code -529697949**

While Android emulator is running CPU is fixed about 40%.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: It might possible due to low memory. Please try to increase your emulator RAM size as well as Disk Drive size and Enable "Cold Boot" then Restart Android studio and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Open your AVD manager

[image]

Edit your memory settings like below

[image]

Comment: I do not know why but i can not change settings. See picture https://ibb.co/jg6c80k

Comment: is your emulator being started? if yes, close it first.